# Need to downsample video to a lower resolution

Tags: video-conversion

I would like to convert **a Mp4 file in HD into a Mp4 file of lower resolution**. Is there any software that can be used for this?

Answer (score 70):

Terminal commands (Which by default are not installed) are:

**MENCODER**

Install it by `sudo apt-get install mencoder`

[mencoder](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mencoder)[image: Install mencoder]

The part about mencoder that you want is the parameter **-vop scale** which tells mencoder to what scale you want the video to go to. This is normal if you want to reduce bandwidth use, lower video size, etc..

`mencoder input.mp4 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mp4 -vop scale=640:480 -oac copy -o output.mp4`

or

`mencoder input.mp4 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mp4 -vf scale=640:480 -oac copy -o output.mp4`

or a simple

`mencoder input.mp4 -vop scale=640:480 -o output.mp4`

Although from my experience is better to include additional information for video and audio like the one above.

**FFMPEG** (Deprecated)

Install it by `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

[ffmpeg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ffmpeg)[image: Install ffmpeg]

Here is an example of ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i input -vf scale=iw/2:-1 output`

Where **IW** = Video Input Width.

Scale = Parameter to scale to. In this case you are dividing the original size by 2 (iw/2)

both of which can provide more information if you either execute them without parameters or variables like just `mencoder` or `ffmpeg` or type for example `man mencoder` or `man ffmpeg` which will give you a VERY extensive little manual on how to work with them.

**AVCONV** <-- I love this guy!

[avconv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libav-tools)[image: Install Avconv]

**To Install** - `sudo apt-get install libav-tools`

**To Run** - `avconv -i input.mp4 -s 640x480 output.mp4`

Where `-i` is for the original input file, `-s` is for the size for each frame and the name of the output final goes in the end.

GUI tools which I love are:

[image]

**AVIDEMUX** - It can resize and lower the size which helps in cases where the objective is to lower size. [avidemux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/avidemux)[image: Install avidemux]

[image]

**HANDBRAKE** - Excellent tool for converting videos and optimizing size. I use it a lot when going from ogg to mp4 with h.264. Lowers A LOT the size. [handbrake](http://packages.ubuntu.com/handbrake)[image: Install handbrake]

[image]

**OPENSHOT** & **PITIVI** - Both are good video editors tha can help lower size when rendering the video. [openshot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openshot)[image: Install openshot]  and [pitivi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pitivi)[image: Install pitivi]

So in conclusion, for direct resizing/scaling you can use the terminal ones. For size you can use all.

Comment: Avidemux **can** resize. and more - checkout the video filters menu

Comment: @artfulrobot Correct. Had to set it to transcode first. +1

Comment: On Ubuntu Precise: avidemux gives warnings about h264 saying that you'll either lose frame accuracy, or get stuttering/crashes. avconv took over an hour on my Intel i5 to process a 13 minute file and generated a much bigger file than the original. I can't get mencoder to work Cannot find codec 'mp4' in libavcodec Couldn't open video filter 'lavc'. Openshot doesn't give much control (bunch of presets, none are what I needed) over output and created files that played at the wrong speed or had choppy audio. :-(

Comment: @artfulrobot - Wow you got problems ^^. Avidemux does say the warnings over h264 because you WILL loose frame accuracy (Not much crash)when transcoding, the only way would be to actually put the same compression/rate/bits/etc.. For the avconv time there has to be a problem. I did a 1 hour 23 minute movie in mp4 format with h264 in about 25 minutes with an i3. With an i7 2600 it went down to 11 minutes. Did you happen to install the restricted extra package

Comment: That's what worked for me, using a 64 bits Manjaro: mencoder MAH09111.MP4 -ovc lavc -vf scale=640:480 -oac pcm -o MAH09111_640x480.mp4

Comment: avconv doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Error is "The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it." But adding -strict -2 doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: Same problem with ffmpeg.

Comment: Problem remains when converted m4v to mp4.

Comment: mencoder maybe works.

Comment: ffmpeg ran 2 to 3 times faster than avconv on my tiny EC2 instance, although I'm not certain I wasn't asking each to do different things - ffmpeg was dividing by 4, avconv was resizing to 480x360, mencoder couldn't decode my file "Couldn't open video filter 'lavc'"

Comment: `avconv` allows for ratio based scale based on current width/height, ex 50% scale `-vf scale=w=iw/2:h=ih/2`, see: https://libav.org/documentation/avconv.html#toc-scale-1

Answer (score 26):

Use `avconv`. Type in terminal

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -s 320x240 output.mp4
```

Replace `320x240` with whatever resolution you want.

There a lot of additional options that you can play with. Do `man avconv` to know more.

Instead, if you don't have `avconv`, you could use ffmpeg.

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Convert:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 320x240 output.mp4
```

Comment: I tried **avconv.** It is giving me **command not found**. I tried everything mentioned above. It is giving me the same answer. It would be really useful if you could suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: See if the edit works.

Comment: Added `-c:a copy` to `avconv` to copy audio stream without reencoding

Comment: Doesn't work, Ubuntu 16.04: `The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.` And `-strict -2` does not change the error.

Comment: @theja You can use the `avconv` command after installing libav-tools `sudo apt-get install libav-tools`

Comment: @6005 I got the same error (also on 16.04) but it worked for me after adding `-strict -2` but this has to be placed right before the name of the output file

Comment: @sunyata Good to know. I hope this helps future readers. Cheers,

Answer (score 24):

Use VLC.

From the Media menu choose "Convert/Save". Add your file(s) to the input and click Convert/Save button.

You'll then be asked to specify an output file, and you can choose a profile and tinker with it, e.g. here I scale the video by 50%:

[image: screenshot]

Click Save.