# Are there any apps to resize videos in Ubuntu?

Tags: video-editor, video-conversion

I have a 20-min video that my friend has recently recorded, but the whole thing occupies 1 G. Is there a way to reduce it to something that can be emailed to people without completely using the quality?

Answer (score 8):

Terminal commands (Which by default are not installed) are:

**MENCODER**

Install it by `sudo apt-get install mencoder`

[mencoder](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mencoder)[image: Install mencoder]

The part about mencoder that you want is the parameter **-vop scale** which tells mencoder to what scale you want the video to go to. This is normal if you want to reduce bandwidth use, lower video size, etc..

`mencoder input.mp4 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mp4 -vop scale=640:480 -oac copy -o output.mp4`

or

`mencoder input.mp4 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mp4 -vf scale=640:480 -oac copy -o output.mp4`

or a simple

`mencoder input.mp4 -vop scale=640:480 -o output.mp4`

Although from my experience is better to include additional information for video and audio like the one above.

**FFMPEG** (Deprecated)

Install it by `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

[ffmpeg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ffmpeg)[image: Install ffmpeg]

Here is an example of ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i input -vf scale=iw/2:-1 output`

Where **IW** = Video Input Width.

Scale = Parameter to scale to. In this case you are dividing the original size by 2 (iw/2)

both of which can provide more information if you either execute them without parameters or variables like just `mencoder` or `ffmpeg` or type for example `man mencoder` or `man ffmpeg` which will give you a VERY extensive little manual on how to work with them.

**AVCONV** <-- I love this guy!

[avconv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libav-tools)[image: Install Avconv]

**To Install** - `sudo apt-get install libav-tools`

**To Run** - `avconv -i input.mp4 -s 640x480 output.mp4`

Where `-i` is for the original input file, `-s` is for the size for each frame and the name of the output final goes in the end.

GUI tools which I love are:

[image]

**AVIDEMUX** - It can resize and lower the size which helps in cases where the objective is to lower size. [avidemux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/avidemux)[image: Install avidemux]

[image]

**HANDBRAKE** - Excellent tool for converting videos and optimizing size. I use it a lot when going from ogg to mp4 with h.264. Lowers A LOT the size. [handbrake](http://packages.ubuntu.com/handbrake)[image: Install handbrake]

[image]

**OPENSHOT** & **PITIVI** - Both are good video editors tha can help lower size when rendering the video. [openshot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openshot)[image: Install openshot]  and [pitivi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pitivi)[image: Install pitivi]

So in conclusion, for direct resizing/scaling you can use the terminal ones. For size you can use all.

Comment: Response [lifted from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/162014/242522).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by FFMPEG (Deprecated).  FFMPEG seems to be alive and well.

Answer (score 4):

Generally for such tasks, you could try [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/)

> HandBrake is a tool for converting video from nearly any format to a selection of modern, widely supported codecs

It should be in the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```

Though 1GB ---> something that can be send by e-mail, sounds rather (read extremely) optimistic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use VLC for that:

- `Media` > `Convert / Save...` (<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>)
- Click <kbd>+ Add...</kbd> and select the file to convert
  [image: File selection]
- Click <kbd>Convert / Save</kbd> and select the "Create new profile" button
  [image: Convert options]
- Give a name to the `Profile Name`, then in the <kbd>Video codec</kbd> tab:

  - make sure you check the `Video` checkbox
  - go to the `Resolution` sub-tab and either select a `Scale` or specify fixed `Frame size`:
    [image]
  - click <kbd>Create</kbd>
- Make sure you selected a `Destination file` before clicking <kbd>Start</kbd>

Then be patient :)